# Modify data in rows and columns with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to modify a specific data points in the pandas data frame under a condition. For example in the following table, I want to divide the data by 2 in column A where only row values of column B is greater than 1.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |

Expected output :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2.5 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |

How can I modify the data frame with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["Column B"] > 1,"Column A"] = df["Column A"]/2
```

Hope it Helps...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df["A"]=df.apply(lambda x:x["A"]/2 if x["B"]>1 else x["A"],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try 'where' which takes the opposite condition and replaces it with the values.

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],'B':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1]})
data.A=data.A.where(data.B<=1,data.A/2)
```